# Is there a good symmetric encryption algorithm that changes ciphertext if password or plaintext changes?

Tags: algorithm, encryption

I want that when the original data or the password changes (I mean, any one of them changes, or both of them change), the encrypted data will always change. In other words, once the encrypted data is certain, then both the original data and the password will be certain, although they are not known to those who don't have the password.

Is there any good symmetric encryption algorithm that fits my specific need?

Comment: Almost anything with any sort of hash?

Comment: You can see more explanations on my need in the comments of one of the answers.

Comment: Edit your question to include those explanatory comments.

Answer (score 1):

*I assume that you use the password to derive the key for the cipher.*

## Changing key

Every modern encryption algorithm produces different ciphertexts when a different key is used. That's just how encryption usually works. If it doesn't have this property then everything is broken. All the usual suspect like AES, Blowfish, 3DES have this property.

## Changing plaintext

The other property is a little harder to do. This runs under the umbrella of semantic security.

Take for example any modern symmetric cipher in ECB mode. If only a single block of plaintext changes then only the same block changes in the ciphertext. So if you encrypt many similar plaintexts, an attacker who observes the ciphertexts can infer relationships between those. **ECB mode is really bad.**

Ok, now take a cipher in CBC mode. If you use the same IV over and over again, then an attacker may infer similar relationships as in ECB mode. If the 10th block of plaintext changes, then the previous 9 blocks will be the same in both ciphertexts. So, if you use a new random IV for every encryption, then there is nothing an attacker can deduce besides the length without breaking the underlying cipher.

> In other words, once the encrypted data is certain, then both the original data and the password will be certain

The previous paragraph may not be completely what you wanted, because now if you encrypt the same plaintext with the same key twice, you get different results (this is a weak security property) due to a random IV. Since you derive the key from a password, you may also derive the IV from the same password. If you use for example PBKDF2, you can set the number of output bits to be the size of key+IV. You will need to use a static salt value.

---

If you don't need that last property, then I suggest you use an authenticated mode like GCM or EAX. When you transmit ciphertext or give the attacker an encryption oracle then there are possible attack vectors when no integrity checks are used. An authenticated mode solves this for you without the need to use an encrypt-then-MAC scheme.

Answer (score 0):

If all you care about is detecting when either the data or the password changes, create a file with the data and then append the password.  Then use a cryptographic hash like [SHA-2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-2) on the file.  If either the data or password changes, the hash will change.

Encryption algorithms are generally used to keep data private or to verify identities.  Hashes are for detecting when two data objects are different.

Comment: I think zhoudu is concerned about the (very small) possibility of two different inputs resulting in the same hashvalue.

Comment: The possibility of two different inputs accidentally producing the same hash value for SHA-2 is so small as to be zero.  If you can deliberately do this, then congratulations you have broken the SHA-2 hash algorithm.  You're famous, at least to computer people!

Comment: In fact, I am considering developing an encryption software that encrypts user's data with user's password. And for decryption, the software needs to know whether the password for decryption is correct. If different combinations of original data and password can result in same encrypted data, then the software will not be able to know whether the password for decryption is correct, because even if the password is incorrect, there may be also original data that results in the same encrypted data by encryption with the incorrect password.

Comment: I have considered using hash for authentication. I considered to use hash of password or of original data. But it is possible, although very little, that different inputs can result in same hash value. So, the method of hash doesn't seem to be very good.

Comment: I have also considered another method: to encrypt user's password with a constant password written in my software, then to encrypt user's data with user's password. This can make sure that incorrect password can always be detected. But it seems that almost all softwares can be disassembled, and then the constant password may be seen by hackers. If the constant password is seen, then user's original data can be decrypted by hackers easily. So this method doesn't seem to be good.

Comment: @zhoudu So, if I understand you correctly, you want to decrypt only when the decryption would actually succeed. This is the authentication property of such block cipher modes like GCM or EAX. See [Why should I use Authenticated Encryption instead of just encryption?](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/12178) I already mentioned this in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

The usual reason for encrypting data is that it will be placed in an insecure environment. If the user's encrypted data is in an insecure environment, an opponent can copy it and use software the opponent obtained or wrote, instead of your software, to try to decrypt it. This is similar to some of the controls put on PDFs in Adobe software, such as not being able to cut and paste from the document. Other brands of software may not enforce the no-cut-and-paste restriction.

If the opponent discerns the encryption algorithm, but uses the wrong password, the chances of getting the correct plain text are very small; for the popular modern algorithms, the chance is small enough to neglect compared to other everyday risks we must endure, such as life on earth being destroyed by a comet.